# How to align text to the left within a border that is aligned to the right

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty aligning text to the left within a border that is aligned to the right. the only way that I was able to align the text/border to the right, was nested within a div. I attempted and failed to align them to the right from css, so I put the content in a div. I'm thinking that the problem is caused by our old friend "Inheritance."

```
 Here's the relevant code   

    <code> css   

        .ex2
             { 
            border-style:solid;
              border-color:#3d2574;
             width:295px;
             height:180px;
             padding:10px;
               border:2px 
                margin:0px;
               z-index:12;
                 }  

            <html>

                <div align="right"> <div class="ex2">
               <style="text-aline=:left;          
             padding:5; font size:3;color="black" ><b><p>*yadda:<br>
            yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda<br><br>
          yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda<br><br> 
          yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda</p>

                                </b>
                       </var>
                 </font>

              </div>
            </div>
              </div>

              </code>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use align="right" instead use  css :

```
float:right
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled and misformatted your `text-align` declaration:

```
<style="text-aline=:left; padding:5; font size:3;color="black">
```

you've written `text-aline=:left` instead of `text-align:left`

The `style` tag itself is used incorrectly too. It should be e.g.

```
<style>.ex2 { text-align:left; padding:5px; font-size:3em; color:black; }</style>
```

Note that I've added a selector (`.ex2`), and added unit values (`px`, `em`) to your `padding` and `font-size` declarations.

Even better, CSS styles should be moved to an external stylesheet (as you've presumably done with your `.ex2` rule).

A few other formatting issues I noticed with your HTML:

- Your color declaration is wrongly formatted. You've written
  `color="black"` instead of `color:black;"`.
- Your `font-size` declaration is missing a hyphen.
- You have a closing `font` tag with no matching opening tag.
- You have a closing `var` tag with no opening tag.
- You have four `div` opening tags and only three closing tags.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I added the float syntax. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The line `<style = "text-aline=:left;`etc is incorrect, you should reference the text you want to align correctly in the css like so:

```
.ex2 { 
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:#3d2574;
     width:295px;
     height:180px;
     padding:10px;
     border:2px 
     margin:0px;
     z-index:12;
     text-align: right;
     padding:5; 
     font size:3;
     color:black;
}
```

Furthermore, there are some other issues with your code:

- you are using the style tag incorrectly. the style tag is simply wrapped around the css you write or it references a css file, you cannot/should not be styling the style tag like an element.
- There is a closing font tag without an opening, however I recommend that you do *not* use the font tag at all.
- There is a closing var tag with no opening.
- your style is unwrapped in style tags.

---

Your new html would look like

```
<style> 
  .ex2 { 
         border-style:solid;
         border-color:#3d2574;
         width:295px;
         height:180px;
         padding:10px;
         border:2px 
         margin:0px;
         z-index:12;
         text-align: right;
         padding:5; 
         font size:3;
         color:black;
    }  
</style>
<div align="right">
    <div class="ex2">
        <b>
        <p>
            *yadda:<br>
             yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda<br>
            <br>
             yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda<br>
            <br>
             yadda,yadda,yadda, yeadda,yadda,yadda
        </p>
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Issue resolved!! I used <code><div style="float: right;"></code> which is what I needed to do anyway since I have content on the left.